# How to add a border to customized nsis installer

Tags: windows, nsis

I am working on customized  installer with the help of  NSIS/MUI2.nsh. I am struggling with adding a border to the installer.

When I work on the welcome and finish pages I just add border to the bitmap(simply draw it) and set it to control id 1044 accordingly. How can I add the border to the license, components or directory pages?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of where you want this border?

Comment: Also on the sides and border at the top horizontal line. 4 lines of border in total. how can i draw it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extra borders by creating extra windows:

```
OutFile Test.exe
RequestExecutionLevel user

Page License "" onLicShow
Page InstFiles

!include nsDialogs.nsh ; WS_*
Function onLicShow
GetDlgItem $5 $hWndParent 0xFFFFFFFF
ShowWindow $5 0 ; Hide the original line
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(pr5,@r0)' ; NSIS v3+
System::Call 'USER32::MapWindowPoints(p0, p$hWndParent, pr0, i1)'
System::Call '*$0(i.r1,i.r2,i.r3,i.r4)'
IntOp $2 $2 - 2 ; Adjust a little up
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0, t"STATIC", p0, i ${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_CHILD}, i 0, i r2, i 9999, i 4, p$hWndParent, p0, p0, p0)p.r0'
SetCtlColors $0 "" 0xff0000 ; Red

System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0, t"STATIC", p0, i ${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_CHILD}, i 0, i 0, i 4, i 9999, p$hWndParent, p0, p0, p0)p.r0'
SetCtlColors $0 "" 0x00ff00 ; Green

System::Call 'USER32::GetClientRect(p$hWndParent,@r0)' ; NSIS v3+
System::Call '*$0(i,i,i.r3,i)'
IntOp $3 $3 - 4 ; X = Window width - border width
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0, t"STATIC", p0, i ${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_CHILD}, i $3, i 0, i 4, i 9999, p$hWndParent, p0, p0, p0)p.r0'
SetCtlColors $0 "" 0xffff00 ; Yellow

System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0, t"STATIC", p0, i ${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_CHILD}, i 0, i 0, i 9999, i 4, p$hWndParent, p0, p0, p0)p.r0'
SetCtlColors $0 "" 0xffffff ; White

FindWindow $1 "#32770" "" $hWndParent ; Find the inner dialog
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0, t"STATIC", p0, i ${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_CHILD}, i 0, i 0, i 9999, i 7, p$1, p0, p0, p0)p.r0'
SetCtlColors $0 "" 0x0000ff ; Blue
FunctionEnd
```

Windows in the inner dialog are only visible on that page, other windows are visible on all pages.